# If $I$ is injective and $P$ is projective, is $\operatorname{Hom}(P,I)$ injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules

In Bourbaki's Algebra, there is the following exercise ($A$ is an arbitrary ring with unity):

---

*Suppose that $I$ is an $(A,A)$-bimodule which is injective as a left $A$-module and a right $A$-module and that for every (left or right) cyclic $A$-module $E\neq 0$, there exists a non-zero $A$-homomorphism of $E$ into $I$. Show that under these conditions, if $P$ is a left projective $A$-module, $\operatorname{Hom}_A(P,I)$ is a right injective $A$-module.*

---

The following straightforward proof does not use the condition on the cyclic modules, so there is probably something wrong with it, and I hope someone can point out the faulty step.

---

$\operatorname{Hom}(P,I)$ can be seen as a right $A$-module in a canonical way, using the bimodule structure of $I$.

To show that $\operatorname{Hom}(P,I)$ is injective, it suffices to show that, for any right $A$-module $N$ and a submodule $N'$ of $N$, the homomorphism $\Phi$ of $\operatorname{Hom}(N,\operatorname{Hom}(P,I))$ into $\operatorname{Hom}(N',\operatorname{Hom}(P,I))$ given by the restriction of mappings is surjective.

Since $I$ is injective, the homomorphism of $\operatorname{Hom}(N,I)$ into $\operatorname{Hom}(N',I)$ given by restriction is surjective. Since $P$ is projective, the induced mapping $\Psi$ of $\operatorname{Hom}(P,\operatorname{Hom}(N,I))$ into $\operatorname{Hom}(P,\operatorname{Hom}(N',I))$ is surjective.

But $\operatorname{Hom}(P,\operatorname{Hom}(N,I))$ is canonically isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}(N,\operatorname{Hom}(P,I))$, and likewise $\operatorname{Hom}(P,\operatorname{Hom}(N',I))$ to $\operatorname{Hom}(N',\operatorname{Hom}(P,I))$. $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ correspond to each other via these isomorphisms, so $\Phi$ must be surjective as well.

---

Where is the mistake? If you think there is none, please tell me so.

Comment: There are situations where the criterion on cyclic modules is unnecessary: consider $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $I=\mathbb{Q}$. Then $\mathrm{Hom}(P,\mathbb{Q})$ is divisible and thus injective as a right $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Answer (score 7):

I didn't analyze what you wrote very carefully, but I do know the answer to your title question.

Suppose $P$ is an $R$-$S$ bimodule which is *flat* as a left $R$ module, and $M$ is an injective right $S$ module. Then $\mathrm{Hom}(P_S,M_S)$ is an injective right $R$ module (where the right $R$ module action is given in the usual way: $(f\cdot r)(x)=f(rx)$ ).

This is the "Injective Producing Lemma" which appears (among other places I'm sure) in Lam's *Lectures on Modules and Rings* pg 61. It's used several times throughout the book.

The proof is really short, and I think essentially says what you have above. Paraphrasing:

> We have the standard isomorphism:
>
> $$\mathrm{Hom}(A_R,\mathrm{Hom}(P_S,M_S)_R)\cong \mathrm{Hom}((A\otimes _R P)_S,M_S)$$
> Since $_R P$ is flat, $-\otimes_R P$ is exact, and since $M_S$ is injective $\mathrm{Hom}(-,M_S)$ is exact. Thus the composition on the right hand side is exact on $A$, and therefore the left hand side is exact on $A$. Consequently, $\mathrm{Hom}(P_S,M_S)$ is an injective right $R$ module.

Comment: I can't make the transfer to the statement of the question. The problem is that $P$ is not assumed to be a bimodule.

Comment: @StefanWalter Sorry: I picked different letters and it looked so similar...! So maybe full projectivity of $P$ is necessary here with the bimodule $M$ to get things going...